# Failed to deploy Artifactory OSS image in Openshift Online 3 Starter by error "Creating user artifactory failed"

Tags: openshift, artifactory, openshift-origin

I'm trying to setup artifactory on Openshift Online 3 Starter using docker image `docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest`from [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker)

But when deploying I got an error
[image]

I tried to create artifactory user by command `oc create serviceaccount artifactory` and then `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z artifactory` but has another error:

Error from server (Forbidden): User "xxxx" cannot get securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope

Answer (score 0):

You need to be cluster admin in order to be able to run:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z artifactory
```

This is because it is granting the right to run things as any user ID, including `root`. This is something that you as a normal user aren't allowed to do.

Further, in OpenShift Online you can only run things in the user ID range you are assigned. You cannot override that, nor will you be granted additional privileges.

You would need to find a version of the image which doesn't require it be run as `root` and which can run as an arbitrary user ID.

Comment: I found that with OpenShift Online Starter account has no way to execute commands above. May be I need to use another plan. Thank you.

Comment: As the answer stated, you need to be a cluster admin, which you aren't going to be unless you own the whole cluster and manage it.